# What change to make in Terraform 1.3.5 file for security group not found error while using security group as data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am in the process of changing Terraform version from 1.1.4 to 1.3.5 and aws provider 4.40.0. The aws eks cluster resource is created with:

```
    resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks-cluster" {
     depends_on = [
       aws_cloudwatch_log_group.eks-cluster,
       aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.masters-attach-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
       aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.masters-attach-AmazonEKSServicePolicy
     ]
     enabled_cluster_log_types = ["api", "audit"]
     name                      = "${var.prefix}-eks-cluster-${var.active_cluster}"
     role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.masters-iam-role.arn
     version                   = var.k8s_version
    
     vpc_config {
       endpoint_private_access = true
       security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.eks-sg.id]
       subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private-subnet-1.id,
         aws_subnet.private-subnet-2.id,
         aws_subnet.private-subnet-3.id,
         aws_subnet.utility-subnet-1.id,
         aws_subnet.utility-subnet-2.id,
       aws_subnet.utility-subnet-3.id]
     }
    }
```

Aws managed node group inside this eks cluster is created with:

```
    resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-grp" {
      cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster.name
      node_group_name = "${var.prefix}-nodes-${var.active_cluster}"
      node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.nodes-iam-role.arn
      subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private-subnet-1.id,
        aws_subnet.private-subnet-2.id, aws_subnet.private-subnet-3.id]
      version = var.k8s_version
      capacity_type   = "ON_DEMAND"
      instance_types = [var.worker_instance_size, var.worker_instance_size_back_up1, var.worker_instance_size_back_up2]
    
      launch_template {
        id      = aws_launch_template.eks-launch_template.id
        version = aws_launch_template.eks-launch_template.latest_version
      }
      lifecycle{
        create_before_destroy = true
      }
    }
```

I am using data source to get the eks created security group (this is created by aws when it creates the managed node group) like this:

```
    data "aws_security_group" "worker-node-security-group" {
      filter {
        name   = "tag:Name"
        values = ["eks-cluster-sg-${var.prefix}-eks-cluster-${var.active_cluster}-*"]
      }
      depends_on = [
        aws_eks_node_group.worker-node-grp,
        aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster
      ]
    }
```

The problem is that with Terraform version 1.1.4, the above code works without any issues, however with terraform 1.3.5 and aws provider 4.40.0 it gives the below error. I Have been trying for a many days now and I dont understand why 1.3.5 causes this issue. How do I fix this?

```
    [31m[31m╷[0m[0m
    [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mno matching EC2 Security Group found[0m
    [31m│[0m [0m
    [31m│[0m [0m[0m  with module.eks-cluster.data.aws_security_group.worker-node-security-group,
    [31m│[0m [0m  on eks-cluster/main.tf line 221, in data "aws_security_group" "worker-node-security-group":
    [31m│[0m [0m 221: data "aws_security_group" "worker-node-security-group" [4m{[0m[0m
    [31m│[0m [0m
    [31m╵[0m[0m
    [0m[0m
```

This is the security group in question. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.html
we dont want to give ssh access to the worker nodes by using the remote_access attribute

Comment: it would be helpful to see a list of security group names that could be searched in. 
I am not 100% but I think that * in your pattern may be a problem, its a string match not a pattern match.

Comment: A question like this was already closed, why spam with the same one multiple times?

Comment: @marko-e, it was closed automatically because I did not word the question correctly. It also didnt answer the problem.

Comment: @Josh Beauregard There is only one security group that has the name matching the string before the *. And I checked the wild card can be used for matching pattern in filter.

Comment: What was the AWS provider version previously?

Comment: It was 4.26.0 @matt-schuchard